# Why does my dog invites affection and then acts aggressive when the person turns to go?

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression

My 2 year old border collie is lovely natured and loves a fuss from people but 6 months ago she started being aggressive when they stop fussing her and move away especially when she is in her cage in the car. She invites them to stroke her, she loves it, then the minute they turn to go she becomes really aggressive and tries to get to them from inside her closed cage.

At about the same time ,although she has always come to coffee shops and eating places and always without exception curled up and laid under the table while we eat. She now acts aggressive when the waitress leaves the table after taking our order and also when they clear the table. Even if they often fuss her she is aggressive when they turn to leave. It’s as though she doesn’t want them to go.

Very confusing for us as she is a lovely natured border collie and very good with the small children. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Please give us some background: do you give her physical training like long walks or agility training? And do give her mental training like obedience training?